# TypeError handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

I use node package Easy-encryption (https://www.npmjs.com/package/easy-encryption). This package encrypt and decrypt strings. If decrypt created easy-encryption string, all right. But if decrypt incorrect string, then server drops and return this:

Example incorrect decrypt:

```
var crypt = new Crypt({
    secret: crypt_config.secret,
    iterations: crypt_config.iterations
});

var result = crypt.decrypt('test');
```

Result:

```
crypto.js:122
  this.push(this._handle.update(chunk, encoding));
                         ^

TypeError: Bad input string
    at TypeError (native)
    at Decipher.Cipher._transform (crypto.js:122:26)
    at Decipher.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:167:10)
    at Decipher.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:155:12)
    ...
```

How to make that when error occured server continues work and error was handled?

Comment: Why do you think that 'test' decrypts correctly? It's not a valid ciphertext, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue execution, encapsulate your code in a try catch statement.

```
var crypt = new Crypt({
    secret: crypt_config.secret,
    iterations: crypt_config.iterations
});

try{
    var result = crypt.decrypt('test');
}
catch(err){
    alert(err);
}
```

But, as the comments say, are you really passing in the right type of data? This won't help you much.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, `decrypt` take string.